# Deploy tomcat with Swing application Runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maven, tomcat

I have swing application, now i want to create Rest web services which will use the same methods pre-defined for the swing application, but the requirement is like when i start my swing application then only tomcat must be get deployed and web services to be available, so I can use those web service for the web/mobile application. My Swing application in maven project and tool is Eclipse.

Comment: not sure i fully understand, but u need to make some changes in your code to be able to run it in tomcat. tomcat is a web-container and can run Servlets. Servlet does not have a main() method and will be triggered upon HTTPRequest or by tomcat by the init() method.read the Servlet API to understand the Servlet lifecycle)

Comment: Separate the functionality you want to use in one or more separate libraries, write a Swing application and web application around those libraries

Comment: any other option to expose my rest web service without tomcat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I don't think that you can deploy tomcat using a swing application. Swing applications are usually standalone executables. Tomcat usually gets installed as a service and then you deploy your web services as a WAR in tomcat. There are some good tutorials on using the tomcat plugin to develop web services in Eclipse. One of the ones that helped me was this one [RESTful with Jersey](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/06/restful-web-services-with-jersey-jax-rs.html#.VhSui3pVhBd)

Comment: any other option to expose my rest web service without tomcat ?

Comment: All of my RESTful web service experience has been with some kind of container.  I've used Weblogic, Jboss, and Tomcat.  I think that Tomcat is the most lightweight and easy to configure.  As far as I know, you have to have some kind of container to host your web services.

Comment: yes that's correct but can i load/deploy tomcat from java program when my swing application starts ?
Basically I want to do same things from mobile which i do with my swing application and have to use the existing code of swing application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right. Apparently you can run tomcat in embedded mode: http://www.hascode.com/2013/07/embedding-jetty-or-tomcat-in-your-java-application/ I didn't realize that was an option since all of my Web service experience has been for enterprise level applications.

Comment: Got the solution with Spring Boot..
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/